# How to request/execute a command on a web page without using a web browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to get the commentary of a football match from the William Hill website.
To get them I need the child elements of id="box_commentaries" to appear.

[image]

To make them appear I need to simulate a click on class="_commentary".

[image]

There are two ways to do this: by clicking directly or calling this function in the console.

[image]

My question is how can I do this without having to open a web browser? I don't want to open a web browser because I'm going to be getting comments from dozens of matches simultaneously every minute and I don't want to consume too much memory since I need to do more things.

The function I used was this:

```
(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('_commentary')[0].click();
  }, 3000);
})();
```

To go directly to the page where the scoreboard is, just follow this link:

f'https://sports.whcdn.net/scoreboards/app/football/index.html?eventId={match_id}&sport=football&locale=en-gb&streamingAvailable=false&showSuggestions=true&expandDetails=true&showStreaming=false&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fsports.williamhill.com'

You just need to change the `match_id` by the id of any live match

[image]

Ex: https://sports.whcdn.net/scoreboards/app/football/index.html?eventId=**28174073**&sport=football&locale=en-gb&streamingAvailable=false&showSuggestions=true&expandDetails=true&showStreaming=false&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fsports.williamhill.com

P.S. I know how to use Selenium and I've written code with it that was very slow. Now I'm looking for other ways to make this request

Answer (score 1):

Consider using https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom

You need to setup it so it loads scripts and such, and it can emulate a browser without running a headless/head browser. Still there might be a chance it won't work if the site has a lot of js that do stuff normally you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of jsdom. I'll study the library and try for it, if it works I'll come back here to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can either use [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/guides/evaluate-javascript) or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) for this. Selenium is ideally suited for the test automation aspect. But in this case, you can use it for your use case. In `puppeteer` you can specify the above `headless`: `true` or `false` like below :

```
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('YOUR_SITE');
```

Similarly, in Selenium you can do the same as below :

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver",options=chrome_options)
    url = "your url here"
    driver.get(url)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but as I said in the P.S. I already know how to use Selenium and even Puppeteer, but I don't want them because it will consume too much resources. So I'm looking for an alternative way without the web browser.